# How to convert from decimal to base 63

Tags: python

This is my first question on the site, and given enough time thinking / searching SO I could probably find the answer, but I just don't have the time, and I think it's a unique enough question to merit asking. This is my code:

```
alpha=list("0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
def encrypt(a):
    b=c=0
    for x in a[::-1]:
        b += (len(alpha)**c)*(alpha.index(x))
        c += 1
    return b
def decrypt(a):
    True
while True:         
    print(encrypt(input(">>> ")))
```

My problem is that it converts 'base 63' to dec just fine, but I have no idea how to convert it BACK to base 63, or the plaintext as it were. I'd imagine the answer is something to do with using int() but I really can't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that decrypt will be given an `int`:

```
def decrypt(a):
    remainder = a
    result = ""
    while remainder > 0:
        result = alpha[remainder % 63] + result
        remainder //= 63
    return result or "0"
```

---

If `a` is a string, then change the first line of the function for `remainder = int(a)`

Comment: The input is a string, so remainder needs to be defined as int(a) - the function will be called with an input().

Comment: I will leave the answer as it is because right now `encrypt(decrypt(n))` and `decrypt(encrypt(s))` work (and that can be used to validate both functions). Of course, use `int(a)` in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

program to convert decimal to base n<65## Heading ##, I created this algorithm for the python shell, it can help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def contri(num,Tx):
#ini Base:
    tr = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','y','z','#','@','*'];
    U = []
    p=0;
    alg = 10+3*(len(str(num)))
    lTx = -10
    Nd = float(num)
    while(lTx<alg):#loop number character alg
      X1 = Tx**alg
      X2 = Tx**(alg+1)
      if(Nd>=X1)and(Nd<X2):
        while(p<=Tx):
          Xa = p*X1
          Xb = (p+1)*X1
          if(Xa<=Nd)and(Xb>Nd):
            Nd-=p*X1
            U.append(tr[p])#decrement block
            if(alg==0):
              U.append('.')#float atribuition
          if((p+1)<Tx):
            p = (p+1)
          else:
            break
      else:
        for caracter in U:
          if caracter != '0':
            U.append('0')
        if(alg==0):
              U += '.'#float atribuition
      p=0;
      alg-=1
      re=""
      i=0
      while(i<len(U)):
              re+=U[i]
              i+=1
    return re
bas = int(input("Input defalt base < 64:\n"))
if(0>bas<62):
bas = 60

while 1:
  n = (input("Input: [number] [base]\n")).split()
  if(len(n)==2):
    res = contri(float(n[0]),int(n[1]));
    print(res)
  else:
    res = contri(float(n[0]),bas);
    print(res)
```

But in the non-numerical character recognition part, it gave a bit of work, and it depends a bit on brute-force script (compare characters), Comparisons of bases (automated result):
[number in base_n](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B39qG-ZgVj_GY3FoTzJ5eE9aSzA), 
[float in bases_n](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B39qG-ZgVj_GUnZvUUdQLUhlNnM)